# Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed with rxjava adapter on room

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using Room with RxJava2 version 1.0.0 in my app. Previously I was using Realm and all was fine. Now when I've migrated on Room I get random rare crashes with similar stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:109)
       at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:100)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:301)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker.run(InvalidationTracker.java:372)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Some times its even don't have room mentions in there. I'm not using any Cursors directly, only thru Room and 3rd party libraries (which I haven't changed during migration).

I've checked Room generated code and it all seems to close Cursors properly.

Any thoughts on what is going on and how I can debug this crashes?

Comment: Also I've set `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(newStrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects().detectLeakedClosableObjects().penaltyLog().build());` and don't see any exceptions in the log.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was in RxJava's `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` for Flowable responses in RxJava Room adapter. Apparently it was starting threads but has never released them.
I've swapped `Schedulers.io()` on fixed thread pool with up to 20 threads and it does go away.

Comment: Hey, I've been experiencing a similar issue, but with LiveData - no RX used. Any ideas or suggestions on fixing this?